# When i upload my site as a wordpress theme on localhost the hole admin panel stops working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

As I said in the title when i upload my project as a wp theme, wordpress stops "working". I mean it shows me an error of uploading imgs even if they are uploading to the folder, I can't search for plugins nor for other themes. Evryrhing gets back to normal when I switch to one of the defalut themes.
I tried literlly evrything and I can't work it out.
So here I am.
Please Help...

P.S.
I use XAMPP in the newest ver.

P.S.P.S.
Apache error.log:

> https://files.fm/u/f7894xzm#_

Comment: Can you type the error message here if you get any?

Comment: No it just loads to infinite

Comment: What is your system specifications. Do you have enough RAM and Disk space to handle that operation?

Comment: I'am using 1TB disk so I'am pretty sure I have enough space ;) (8GB RAM)

Comment: Look in the error logs \apache\logs Probs want to put what it says in there on your post

Comment: I uploaded my error file on the post